# Unlimited Values Weight

Tags: entities

Currently I have a field that allows unlimited values, and it's displayed as a video player, using user-input URL from that field. Now I would like to do some custom coding or whatever it takes to somehow pick the first URL (the one at the very top), so I can have the video player play only one URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-value text field, and assuming D7, the values are something like this:

```
// if set, this is the first value...
$node->FIELD_NAME[$node->language][0]['value']
// if at least one set, this is the last value...
$node->FIELD_NAME[$node->language][count($node->FIELD_NAME[$node->language])-1]['value']
```

so depending on what you mean by 'on top,' one of these values is most probably what you are looking for.  (If D6, just take out the `[$node->language]` part)